# How to debug msgpack serialisation issue in Google Cloud Dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spacy, msgpack

I have a Google Cloud Dataflow job with which I would like to extract named entities from a text using a specific `spacy` model `neural coref`.

Running the extraction without beam I can extract entities but when I try to run it with the `DirectRunner` the job fails due to a serialisation error from `msgpack`. I am not sure how to proceed in debugging this problem.

My requirements are quite barebones with requirements of:

```
apache-beam[gcp]==2.4
spacy==2.0.12
ujson==1.35
```

The issue might be something related to how spacy and beam are interplaying as the stacktrace shows spacy spouting out some of its methods which it shouldn't be doing.

Weird spacy log behaviour from stacktrace:

```
T4: <class 'entity.extract_entities.EntityExtraction'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x1126c0398>
T4: <class 'spacy.lang.en.English'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x1126b54b0>
D2: <dict object at 0x1126d1168>
F2: <function is_alpha at 0x11266d320>
# F2
F2: <function is_ascii at 0x112327c08>
# F2
F2: <function is_digit at 0x11266d398>
# F2
F2: <function is_lower at 0x11266d410>
# F2
F2: <function is_punct at 0x112327b90>
# F2
F2: <function is_space at 0x11266d488>
# F2
F2: <function is_title at 0x11266d500>
# F2
F2: <function is_upper at 0x11266d578>
# F2
F2: <function like_url at 0x11266d050>
# F2
F2: <function like_num at 0x110d55140>
# F2
F2: <function like_email at 0x112327f50>
# F2
Fu: <functools.partial object at 0x11266c628>
F2: <function _create_ftype at 0x1070af500>
# F2
T1: <type 'functools.partial'>
F2: <function _load_type at 0x1070af398>
# F2
# T1
F2: <function is_stop at 0x11266d5f0>
# F2
D2: <dict object at 0x1126b7168>
T4: <type 'set'>
# T4
# D2
# Fu
F2: <function is_oov at 0x11266d668>
# F2
F2: <function is_bracket at 0x112327cf8>
# F2
F2: <function is_quote at 0x112327d70>
# F2
F2: <function is_left_punct at 0x112327de8>
# F2
F2: <function is_right_punct at 0x112327e60>
# F2
F2: <function is_currency at 0x112327ed8>
# F2
Fu: <functools.partial object at 0x110d49ba8>
F2: <function _get_attr_unless_lookup at 0x1106e26e0>
# F2
F2: <function lower at 0x11266d140>
# F2
D2: <dict object at 0x112317c58>
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x110e38168>
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x112669c58>
# D2
# Fu
F2: <function word_shape at 0x11266d0c8>
# F2
F2: <function prefix at 0x11266d1b8>
# F2
F2: <function suffix at 0x11266d230>
# F2
F2: <function get_prob at 0x11266d6e0>
# F2
F2: <function cluster at 0x11266d2a8>
# F2
F2: <function _return_en at 0x11266f0c8>
# F2
# D2
B2: <built-in function unpickle_vocab>
# B2
T4: <type 'spacy.strings.StringStore'>
# T4
```

My current hypothesis is that perhaps there is some problem with my `setup.py` but I am not sure what is causing the issue currently.

The full stacktrace is:

```
/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msgpack_numpy.py:183: DeprecationWarning: encoding is deprecated, Use raw=False instead.
  return _unpackb(packed, **kwargs)
/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msgpack_numpy.py:132: DeprecationWarning: encoding is deprecated.
  use_bin_type=use_bin_type)
T4: <class 'entity.extract_entities.EntityExtraction'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x1126c0398>
T4: <class 'spacy.lang.en.English'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x1126b54b0>
D2: <dict object at 0x1126d1168>
F2: <function is_alpha at 0x11266d320>
# F2
F2: <function is_ascii at 0x112327c08>
# F2
F2: <function is_digit at 0x11266d398>
# F2
F2: <function is_lower at 0x11266d410>
# F2
F2: <function is_punct at 0x112327b90>
# F2
F2: <function is_space at 0x11266d488>
# F2
F2: <function is_title at 0x11266d500>
# F2
F2: <function is_upper at 0x11266d578>
# F2
F2: <function like_url at 0x11266d050>
# F2
F2: <function like_num at 0x110d55140>
# F2
F2: <function like_email at 0x112327f50>
# F2
Fu: <functools.partial object at 0x11266c628>
F2: <function _create_ftype at 0x1070af500>
# F2
T1: <type 'functools.partial'>
F2: <function _load_type at 0x1070af398>
# F2
# T1
F2: <function is_stop at 0x11266d5f0>
# F2
D2: <dict object at 0x1126b7168>
T4: <type 'set'>
# T4
# D2
# Fu
F2: <function is_oov at 0x11266d668>
# F2
F2: <function is_bracket at 0x112327cf8>
# F2
F2: <function is_quote at 0x112327d70>
# F2
F2: <function is_left_punct at 0x112327de8>
# F2
F2: <function is_right_punct at 0x112327e60>
# F2
F2: <function is_currency at 0x112327ed8>
# F2
Fu: <functools.partial object at 0x110d49ba8>
F2: <function _get_attr_unless_lookup at 0x1106e26e0>
# F2
F2: <function lower at 0x11266d140>
# F2
D2: <dict object at 0x112317c58>
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x110e38168>
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x112669c58>
# D2
# Fu
F2: <function word_shape at 0x11266d0c8>
# F2
F2: <function prefix at 0x11266d1b8>
# F2
F2: <function suffix at 0x11266d230>
# F2
F2: <function get_prob at 0x11266d6e0>
# F2
F2: <function cluster at 0x11266d2a8>
# F2
F2: <function _return_en at 0x11266f0c8>
# F2
# D2
B2: <built-in function unpickle_vocab>
# B2
T4: <type 'spacy.strings.StringStore'>
# T4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/main.py", line 24, in run
    entities = records | 'ExtractEntities' >> beam.ParDo(EntityExtraction())
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 784, in __init__
    super(ParDo, self).__init__(fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 638, in __init__
    self.fn = pickler.loads(pickler.dumps(self.fn))
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 204, in dumps
    s = dill.dumps(o)
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 259, in dumps
    dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, fmode, recurse)#, strictio)
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 252, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 172, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 841, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 692, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 172, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 841, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/Users/chris/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "vectors.pyx", line 108, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.__reduce__
  File "vectors.pyx", line 409, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.to_bytes
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 485, in to_bytes
    serialized[key] = getter()
  File "vectors.pyx", line 404, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.to_bytes.serialize_weights
  File "/Users/chris/coref_entity_extraction/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msgpack_numpy.py", line 165, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 282, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 288, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 285, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 232, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 279, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
TypeError: can not serialize 'buffer' object
```

I have no idea about how to debug this issue with beam. To reproduce the whole issue I have setup a repo with instructions about how to set everything: https://github.com/swartchris8/coref_barebones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got rid of the above the issue by changing the package versions installed. I do think it debugging the beam setup process is quite painful though my approach was just to manually try different package permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to run the same code from a regular Python program (not from a Beam DoFn) ?

If not, check whether you are storing any non-serializable state in a Beam DoFn (or any other function that will be serialized by Beam). This prevents Beam runners from serializing these functions (to be sent to workers) hence should be avoided.

Comment: The code ran when I called it directly, failure was only happening when executing the code through beam. So when I called it through beam's `DirectRunner` for example it would cause code failure.